# why is my message box not working

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Here is my code:
It is meant to call a invalidinput when `dblprevious` is greater than `dblcurrent` but it is show negative outputs instead I know its got to be simple

```
    Public Class Form1
'names the the class veriables
Dim dblCurrent As Double
Dim dblPervious As Double
Private Sub invalidinput()
    Const Message As String = "check your input"
    Const title As String = " Attention!"
    Const buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK
    MessageBox.Show(Message, title, buttons)
End Sub

Private Sub Total()

    Dim dblTotalP As Double
    Dim dblTotalG As Double
    Const dblPerGC As Double = 5.15
    Const dbltMinC As Double = 19.69

    'stores the veriables
    Double.TryParse(txtCurrentreading.Text, dblCurrent)
    Double.TryParse(txtPerivousreading.Text, dblPervious)
    dblTotalG = dblCurrent - dblPervious
    dblTotalP = dblTotalG / 1000 * dblPerGC
    If dblTotalP < dbltMinC Then
        dblTotalP = dbltMinC
    End If


    'displays totals
    lblTotalG.Text = dblTotalG
    lblTotalP.Text = dblTotalP.ToString("C2")
End Sub

Private Sub bntExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bntExit.Click
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub txtCurrentreading_keypress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtCurrentreading.KeyPress
    'allows text box to accept only numbers and the back space key

    If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtPerivousreading_keypess(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtPerivousreading.KeyPress
    'allows text box to accept only numbers and the back space key


    If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub bntCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bntCalculate.Click

    'determines which calculations to do
    If dblCurrent >= dblPervious Then
        Call Total()
    ElseIf dblPervious < dblCurrent Then
        Call invalidinput()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: use your debugger it's part of MS Access and it will help you figure out what the problem is you can set a break point and step through the code line by line.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and specially read the very helpful page linked at its bottom on debugging small programs. Many people find that creating an [mcve] helps them to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: You don't need to use the `Call` keyword. It's just superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is meant to call a invalidinput when dblprevious is greater than
>   dblcurrent

Change:

```
If dblCurrent >= dblPervious Then
    Call Total()
ElseIf dblPervious < dblCurrent Then
    Call invalidinput()
End If
```

To:

```
If dblCurrent >= dblPervious Then
    Call Total()
Else
    Call invalidinput()
End If
```

Your original check in the else block of `If dblPervious < dblCurrent Then` directly contradicts what your requirements dictated!  If "dblCurrent" is not greater than or equal to "dblPervious", then "dblPervious" must be greater than "dblCurrent", thus allowing us to remove the second check altogether.

Comment: Stupid question...if `Total()` parses the values from your TextBoxes into "dblCurrent" and "dblPervious" variables, how can you use those variables values directly above that call in your `If` statement...before they've been assigned?  What are you expecting to happen there?  You're also not taking into account what should happen if `Double.TryParse()` fails.

Comment: oh my god thank you didn't notice that till you said it that fixed it